# PHPUnit testing exceptions with onlyMethods

Tags: php, phpunit

PHPUnit version 10.5.9

I am getting the following message when I run my code and my test is failing

1. UserTest::testNotificationThrowException
   Failed asserting that exception of type "Exception" is thrown.

The test

```
    /**
     * @expectedException Exception
     */
    public function testNotificationThrowException()
    {
        $user = new User;
        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(Mailer::class)
            ->onlyMethods(['sendMessage'])
            ->getMock();

        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('sendmessage')
            ->with($this->throwException(new Exception));

        $this->expectException(Exception::class);

        $user->setMailer($mock);
        $result = $user->notify('hello');
    }
```

The code I am testing

```
class Mailer
{
    /**
     * Send a message
     *
     * @param string $email The email address
     * @param string $message The 
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     * @return boolean True if sent, false otherwise
     */
    public function sendMessage($email, $message)
    {
        if(empty($email))
        {
            throw new Exception;
        }
        // Use mail() or PHPMailer for example
        sleep(3);

        echo "send '$message' to '$email'";

        return true;
    }
}
```

I was expecting the tests to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the way you define the mock's behaviour here:

```
        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('sendmessage')
            ->with($this->throwException(new Exception));
```

The `with()` method defines *the parameters which the method expects to receive*. That can be a literal value, or a *constraint*; for example:

```
        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('sendmessage')
            ->with($this->stringContains('@'), 'Message')
```

What you are trying to define is the *behaviour* of the method when it is called - you are creating a "mock implementation", not a "spy". For that, you want to say it "will" throw an exception:

```
        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('sendmessage')
            ->will($this->throwException(new Exception));
```

There is also a short-hand method, `willThrowException`:

```
        $mock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('sendmessage')
            ->willThrowException(new Exception);
```

If you don't actually care *for this test* how often `sendmessage` is called, only that it throws an exception every time, you don't need the `expects`:

```
        $mock->method('sendmessage')
            ->willThrowException(new Exception);
```